# RStudio won't open in Windows 10 (HP Elitebook laptop)

Tags: r, windows, installation, rstudio, failed-installation

I have just been upgraded to Windows 10 on my company laptop and I have installed R (64-bit 3.5.0) and RStudio desktop (latest version, installed a couple of days ago). Unfortunately RStudio just will not open (click the launch icon and nothing happens).

I have looked through https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start and not had any luck yet. My findings as follows:

**1. Check for Startup Files** = there are no .Rprofile, .Renviron, and .RData files there.

**2. RStudio cannot find R** = see question below.

**3. Check firewall and proxy settings** = I understand from my IT colleagues that we don't have any blocks like this.

**4. Reset RStudio's state** = this didn't make any difference. The folder just recreated itself. I also checked the log file (this is blank).

**5. Using Macports R** = n/a.

Thus, I had two questions:

**QUESTION 1:** re. 2.: when I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on opening RStudio, still nothing happens. Is there possibly another way to set the search path for RStudio? Or a different keyboard shortcut in Windows 10? Also, just to note this is the message I get in R (I guess the tilde aren't a problem?

[image]

**QUESTION 2:** any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**FIX IDENTIFIED BY MY IT DEPT:**

*CAUSE*: There appears to be a conflict between rStudio and the so-called 'Wacom ISD Service' on my laptop [which I believe is to do with the tablet/touchscreen functionality].

*FIX*: In Windows, go to >> Computer Management >> Services & Applications >> Services, disable 'Wacom ISD Service' [set 'startup type' to 'manual'].